# Is it possible to travel from Korčula to Dubrovnik in October?

Tags: transportation, buses, ferries, croatia, dubrovnik

We will be travelling to Croatia in October with a limited time and are trying to figure out if it is possible to go from Split to Hvar and on to Korčula (seems like ferry still runs). Cannot seem to get from  Korčula to Dubrovnik without back tracking to Split.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Jadrolinija (http://www.jadrolinija.hr/) the main ferry provider in Croatia only runs Korcula to Dubrovnik June - September. If you go to the link above, the first field is date, the second is port of origin and third field is port where you want to go. If you select a date in Oct you will notice Dubrovnik is no longer an option.

However Kapetan Luka (http://www.krilo.hr/en/sailing_schedule.html) does SPLIT - MILNA - HVAR - KORČULA - DUBROVNIK from May to 18th October but it is a passenger ferry only (no vehicles).

Most ferries run a reduced (or no) schedule during winter in Croatia.

Comment: I was just wondering, the "small" connection, Korcula to Orebic - that runs all the time does it ??

Comment: @Joe Blow : It does. http://www.jadrolinija.hr/docs/default-source/red-plovidbe/2014/splitsko/634-2014-zima-hr.pdf?sfvrsn=2  However bus service from Orebic to Dubrovnik, although existing is not very frequent.